# error in the code while creating login page

Tags: html, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function LoginForm({ Login, error }) {
    const[details, setDetails] = useState({name:"", email:"", password:""});

const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    Login(details);
}

return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
    <div className="form-inner">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        {/* Error */}
        <div className = "form-group">
            <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>

        </div>
        <div className="form-group"> 
            <label htmlFor="email"> Email: </label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
         </div>
         <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
         </div>
         <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>
   </form> 
)
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: What error? More details please.

Comment: I don't know what the error is but you aren't updating your state based on the inputs so it's always going to be empty strings.

Comment: it says Login is not a function

Comment: How are you passing Login as props?

Comment: Yes, @BasvanderLinden, passed LOGIN as a prop in App.js file

Comment: function LoginForm({ Login, error }) {
    const[details, setDetails] = useState({name:"", email:"", password:""});

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        Login(details);
    }

Comment: What I meant with my earlier question was: What value are you passing to the `Login` prop on `LoginForm`? If you aren't passing a function as a value to this prop that would explain the error you mentioned.